# Are Carnot groups ever CAT() spaces?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, metric-spaces, non-positive-curvature

Let $G$ be a free Carnot group of homogeneous dimension $d$, equipped with the Carnot–Carathéodory metric.  Is $(G,d)$ ever $\operatorname{CAT}(\kappa)$ for some $\kappa\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No: a result of Pauls even asserts that any nonabelian Carnot group has no quasi-isometric embedding into any CAT(0) space. (Certainly it's easier to directly prove it's not CAT(0)). [Note: free Carnot group has no sense: you need to specify the nilpotency length $k$ and number of generators $r$. It's non-abelian iff $\min(k,r)\ge 2$.]

Comment: @YCor Do you have a reference to this; I'ld like to read more.

Comment: Scott D. Pauls. The large scale geometry in nilpotent Lie groups.
Commun. Anal. Geom. 9(5), 951-982, 2001.